# Node File transfer uploads x bytes of image in images directory but is corrupt

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, filestream

I am using `Busboy` module of Node for parsing files. First upload a file -> Push that uploaded file to images directory. I dont know why but the code is transferring bytes i.e. it does create a image with proper bytes but when clicked on file, its corrupt. Here is my code:

```
var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
      console.log('File [' + fieldname + ']: filename: ' + filename + ', encoding: ' + encoding + ', mimetype: ' + mimetype);

      file.on('data', function(data) {
        var fstream = fs.createWriteStream('./images/' + filename); 
        file.pipe(fstream);
        fstream.on('close', function () {
            console.log("Upload Finished of " + filename);

        });
        console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] got ' + data.length + ' bytes');
      });
      file.on('end', function() {
        console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] Finished');
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`data` events *can* be emitted *multiple* times. The solution here is simple: just pipe `file` to a writable stream once. For example:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var path = require('path');

// ...

var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
  // You will want to somehow sanitize `filename` if you are going to use
  // it when use it as part of the filename on disk, as it could be maliciously
  // constructed to overwrite to other parts of your filesystem.
  //
  // The solution I use here is to simply hash the filename, but you could
  // use `path.resolve('./images/', filename)` instead and check that the
  // result starts with `__dirname + '/images/'`.
  var ext = path.extname(filename);
  filename = crypto.createHash('sha1')
                   .update(filename, 'utf8')
                   .digest('hex') + ext;

  var diskStream = fs.createWriteStream('./images/' + filename);
  file.pipe(diskStream).on('finish', function() {
    console.log('Finished writing file');
  });
});
```